# Не получается поместить открытый ключ на сервер через ssh (windows)

Tags: сервер

Всем привет!

Нужна помощь, не получается переместить открытый ключ на сервер. Предварительно сгенерировал пару ключей: открытый и закрытый. Дальше командой cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub перемещаю ключ на сервер, но в терминале я вижу, что нет такого файла по данному пути. Что не так? Я пробовал прописывать путь полностью cat /Users/tester/.ssh/id_rsa.pub - результат тот же..

```
`tester@ZC68280 ~
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\tester/.ssh/id_rsa):
C:\Users\tester/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\tester/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\tester/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:XuOMDpebvGKnk43kAj3W/gOYE4MegyqaPMhsQH9D/ck tester@ZC68280
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|                 |
|                 |
| . .  .          |
|..+ o. .         |
|o..+.*  S +      |
|+ o.Bo+. E .     |
|O. o.*o== o      |
|+*  . O=+o       |
|. .  o.*Bo       |
+----[SHA256]-----+

tester@ZC68280 ~
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat: /home/tester/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не /home/ и не /Users/, а /cygdrive/c/Users/ - вы ж в винде

Comment: @
andreymal, спасибо огромное. Так получилось!